# Using Firefox's Network tab without the debugger halting the page?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I would like to use the *Network* tab to see what resources the page downloads while I'm interacting with it.

The problem is that, when I have the *Network* tab shown, if I then click any element on the page, the debugger sets a breakpoint (I'm switched to the *Debugger* tab) and this effectively prevents me from using the page, as everything halts. I can click the debugger's "play" button but soon the debugger breaks again.

Can I somehow disable the code debugger? I'm interested only in network traffic.